# Eclipse IDE как отключить валидатор

Tags: html, eclipse, ide

Обновил Eclipse IDE до последней версии (2023-12 (4.30.0)).
Теперь среда разработки подчеркивает мне весь html код желтой волнистой линией (как на скриншоте), указывая на безобидные ошибки, которые меня не волнуют, что только мешает. До обновления такого не было. Я хочу отключить это подчеркивание html кода. Как мне это сделать, не откатывая обновление? Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]